# Golang-Postgres ..Closing database connection not working for particular query

Tags: database, postgresql, go, postgresql-9.4

I am using golang to access postgresql. 
This is my function

```
for {
    db, err := database.GetNewConnection(dbname)

    err = db.QueryRow("SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(1),0) FROM table").Scan(&count)

    if count == 0 {

        var insert = "INSERT INTO table(last_update_time,next_update_time,schedule_frequency)" +
            "VALUES($1,$2,$3)"
        prep_ins, err := db.Prepare(insert)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        _, err = prep_ins.Exec(cur_time, 1464718530, 86400)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer prep_ins.Close()
        defer db.Close()
    } else {
        var sel_str = "SELECT next_update_time FROM table"
        prep_update, err := db.Prepare(sel_str)
        if err != nil {

            return
        }
        _, err = prep_update.Exec()
        if err != nil {
            defer prep_update.Close()
            return
        }
        defer prep_update.Close()
        defer db.Close()
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * 60 * time.Second)
}
```

Every 10 mins , this function will run and execute those statement. Its working fine but the connection will be in idle state. I am checking using `pg_stat_activity`, the state is idle only. Every 10 mins, new connection will be created and went to idle state.so its keep on increasing. i don't know why its happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` loop is an infinite loop and it will never return. This means that defers will never be executed and the connections won't be closed. You need to add explicit `db.Close()` at the end of the loop.

Also move the initialization of `db` out of the loop if you don't need a new connection every time you perform the task. You can just create a single connection and reuse it. If you do this, move `defer` statement just below the initialization of `db`. If the database operations return some errors then defers will close the connection.

```
db, err := database.GetNewConnection(dbname)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("Error in creating database connection: %+v", err)
}
defer db.Close()
for {

    // ...

    db.Close()
}
```

By doing this you ensure that the connection gets closed on every return path put of the function (https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)

If you still leave `db` initialization in the loop, remove the `defers` since they'll only add to the defer stack while the db connection will be closed explicitly.

Comment: I just realized you are never returning from the function. It's an infinite loop. Defers only fire when you exit the function. Change the defers to explicit `db.Close()` at the end of the `for` loop. Leave the defers describe above since they'll close the db in case of errors.

Comment: if i forget to close the prepare statement but closing the connection means  that connection will be in idle state or connection will get close .??

Comment: You should always ensure that each connection is closed. Don't assume anything and make sure that once a file or a connection is open, you close it either explicitly or by using defers. In your case closing the connection will close it but prepare statement might not get closed automatically and may leak resources. Refer to postgres api docs.

Answer (score 2):

As @abhink has pointed out, your defer statement is not being called due to forever running `for` loop. Your implementation for scheduled execution of a piece of code using `for` loop is not optimal.

You should be using golang channels instead.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    //You can configure your tick for 10 mnts.
    tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
    //some exit condition
    exit := time.After(1000 * time.Millisecond)
    for {
        select {
        case <-tick:
            poke()
        case <-exit:
            fmt.Println("Exit")
            return
        default:
            fmt.Println("    .")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}

func poke() {
    fmt.Println("Opening connection")
    defer fmt.Println("Closing connection")
    fmt.Println("Inserting into Database")
}
```

You can change `pock()` function to insert record into database. And you can configure ticker to tick at every 10 mnts. Since every tick triggers a new function call, your defer will be called once `pock()` function execution completes.

Refer this go playground snippet https://play.golang.org/p/1fQgbmI9LY

Answer (score 1):

`defer` functions are only called when the function returns. In your loop the `defer db.Close()` are never executed while the loop is active, hence the functions never called.

You can wrap the logic in the `for` in a **closure** to effect the defers:

```
for{
   func(){
       // inner code 
   }()
   time.Sleep(10 * 60 * time.Second)
}
```